# jQueryui accordion autoheight: false content scrolls out of view

Tags: accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using autoheight:false to get rid of the scrolls and (what I think is an odd default) the fixed height of accordion content. However, when you click to open the next header, the content above(or below) collapses and your active header content scrolls out of view or opens in the middle of the content. I understand why this happens; however is there a way to keep your current (the "active") header in place so the content doesn't jump around?

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        autoHeight: false
})
```